# How do you fork a repo whose upstream you've already forked?

Tags: github, bitcoin

I want to fork namecoin/namecoin, but I've already forked bitcoin/bitcoin.  The latter is the upstream parent of the former.  The forkchain is:

bitcoin/bitcoin -> vinced/namecoin -> namecoin/namecoin

When I fork namecoin/namecoin, Github just redirects me to my myuserid/bitcoin fork, instead of creating a new myuserid/namecoin fork.  It appears to Github that they are the same project, but they are not.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this "officially", but you can always add another remote for bitcoin and fetch from that.

```
git remote add bitcoin-orig git://the/bitcoin/repo/path

git fetch bitcoin-orig

# Merge into your 'master' (CAUTION: This might go badly)
git merge bitcoin-orig/master  

# Create a local branch based on the origin
git co -b bitcoin-orig-master bitcoin-orig/master  

# Take an individual commit from the original repo and put it into your 'master'
git log bitcoin-orig/master && git cherry-pick <SOME SHA>
```