# How to fork a repository on a github, if I have earlier forked another repository which is already a fork of the needed one?

Tags: github, fork

Some time ago I have forked a repository B which is a fork of another repository A on github.
Let's assume, that my forked repository is C.
Now I wanted to contribute directly to repository A.
Therefore I wanted to fork repository A, but instead of creating a new fork (e.g. D), github brings me to my previously created repository C.
I don't want to delete repository C, but I need to start working on my new changes related directly to A.
How can I do it?

**Update**
I have found a very similar question: [How can I fork the original repo when I've already forked a different fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338240/how-can-i-fork-the-original-repo-when-ive-already-forked-a-different-fork).
However I have a problem which is not answered in answers to the above question.

The "intermediate fork" - B does not contain all branches from the original A. Assuming, that I keep working on C and just create a new branch, I don't know how could I base my new branch on a branch of A which is not included in B?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have to add another remote (manually) what's not so hard as you just copy/adjust a line in your git config.

Fetch all and rebase properly. When sending your pull request make sure you send it to the upstream fork.

Comment: I hope that the above operation can be done "per branch", so that I can have one branch based directly to the A repository and my old branch still based on the B repository?

Comment: Of course, rebase actually creates a new set of commits, so as long as you keep a reference to the original branch (e.g. creating another branch just there) you will have both, the rebased and the original set of commits.